# How to remove space in dictionary in python?

Tags: dictionary, key-value

how to remove space before value in dictionary
example:

before:

```
{'tom': 'pass', 'mary': 'pass', 'joan': 'fail'}
```

after:

```
 {'tom':'pass', 'mary':'pass', 'joan':'fail'}
```

Comment: doesn't make difference if you have spaces or not... for example when you retrieve the key 'tom' the value will be in both case 'pass'; it's just data display difference

Comment: Saying what @Carlo1585 said a different way, a the same dictionaries with and without spaces is irrelevant – the representation in whatever text editor you're using might be different (as you show above), but to Python, those to two are identical and you're able to run identical operations on both.